# Capturing href and prevent event default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Not sure why the code is not working. The javascript is not printing the alert box nor preventing the event default. I was under the assumption that the data would load asynchronously keeping me on the same page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page"> 
<div data-role="header"></div> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <p id = "heading">Is Nursing For You?</p>
        <br/>
        <div id = "div1" align="center"></div>
    </div> 
<div data-role="footer" id = "foot" data-position="fixed">
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><h1 id = "alignLeft">Future Goals</th></h1>
        <th><h1 id = "socialMediaText alignCenter">Get Social With Us!</h1>
</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id = "alignLeft">Telephone: 304-444-39876</td>
    <tr>
        <td = "alignLeft">Email: futurenurseky@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
</table>
</div> 
</div> 

This is where im having the trouble at. Not sure why the alert is not sending or redirecting me.
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#div1").load("FONWVhp.php");
    $('#div1').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
});




    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the Fp.php which is called when the page is loaded but once the page is loaded there are href's that are displayed. so when the person clicks the href the page will stay but the data will change and get the info coming from articles.php (at the bottom).

```
$sqlPAQuery = "SELECT pages.pageId, pages.pageTitle FROM pages order by 
pages.pageId";
$paqueryResult = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlPAQuery);
while ($paqueryRow = mysqli_fetch_object($paqueryResult))
{


$pages = "<div class='center-wrapper'><a href = articles.php?
pageId=".$paqueryRow->pageId."><button class= center-wrapper'>".$paqueryRow-
>pageTitle."</button></a><br/><br/></div>";
echo $pages;

}
```

articles.php

```
$sqlARTICLEQuery = "SELECT * FROM articles where pageId=".$_GET['pageId']." 
order by articleId";
$articlequeryResult = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlARTICLEQuery);
while ($articlequeryRow = mysqli_fetch_object($articlequeryResult))
{
$articles ="<div id = 'div1' class='center-wrapper'><a href = 
article.php?articleId=".$articlequeryRow->articleId."><button id 
='wrapper'>".$articlequeryRow->articleTitle."</button></a><br/><br/></div>";

echo $articles;
}
```

Comment: Add the event parameter to the  `click` handler

Comment: Just to inform, you have two divs with the same id `div1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [wait for the div contents to load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) before manipulating it. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#div1").load('FONWVhp.php', function() {
        $('#div1 div.center-wrapper a button').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert($(this).parent().attr('href'));
        });
    });
});
```

Also, I've corrected some mistakes in your code:

1. Instead of `$('#div1').click(...)` use `$('#div1 div.center-wrapper a button').click(...)`.
2. I suppose you want the anchor's href, so you need to use `alert($(this).parent().attr('href'))`.

Comment: This ended up taking my buttons away when I replaced with this code?

Comment: Can you include the code for `Fp.php` in the question?

Comment: i included the fp.php page and my articles page

Comment: Ok, you just need to pay special attention to your selectors. You did not observe that your buttons are inside another `div` (`#center`). Please test the updated code.

Comment: i cut the a button from the selector tag and now the dialog box pops up but the dialog box says undefined.

Comment: Please do as I suggested, with the exact same code that is currently in your question. That would solve your problem. I can't help you if you end up testing the solution in a changed code that is different from the original you've posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160148/discussion-between-adam-zeigler-and-karliwson).

Answer (score 0):

just put an e / event in the function

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#div1").load("Fp.php"); 
     $('div.div1 a button').click(function(e){ 
         e.preventDefault(); 
         alert($(this).attr('href')); 
     });
 });
</script>
```